# Header Files in C-language and Reusability of Object Oriented Programming?

Tags: c, oop, header-files, code-reuse

In interview I was ask that as re-usability is one of the main advantages of Object Oriented Programming but it can also be achieved by include header files in C language? So what is the difference in OOP re-usability and C Header files?

Comment: OOP re-usability is the concept where you could re use the existing code, data and classes that you have. C Header files is a good sample of the application of it where the consumers of the header files could use libraries anytime they want to

Comment: so what is the difference? Is there any extra advantages in OOP reusable code than Header files?

Comment: header files is a example of OOP reusability..,

Comment: Who ever said code reuse is exclusive to OOP? You can have have code reuse without OOP (though the details of how it's achieved may differ - of course). Every decent functional programming project does it, and some procedural code is written to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "re-usability" you are simply implying that code does not need to be repeated in each code module, then yes, a header-file in C accomplishes that task because it allows the declarations for functions and variables defined with external linking in one code module to be used in another code module without the user having to re-type all those declarations and/or attempt to place every definition of every function that would normally be part of a library into each code module.  Thus the duplication of code is prevented.

Object-oriented programming through the use of inheritance and polymorphism in languages like C++ and Java have a similar effect ... you define an interface and/or a base-class once, and then you are able to "include" that code via inheritance in another class.  Additionally, virtual methods along with polymorphism allows you to write functions that take a single base-class type as an argument, yet call code that is actually defined in a derived class-type.  This essentially means you can call *new* code (i.e., your derived class), in *old* code (i.e., the function that accepted a base-class type).  For instance, as a library developer, you could define a set of base-class types/interfaces, and a user could derived from those base-classes, yet still use them effectively in the same functions that were included with the library that accept arguments of the base-class type.  Thus you are not forced to reduplicate those functions ... they are still usable by your "new" derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, without OOP and just using included headers, you can use an existing function without needing to write it again yourself.

However, if you intend to use a very similar, but slightly different function, you have no choice but to write it yourself. You can not reuse the original function in this case, you have to write a new one.

Advantage of OOP: If that function were a class instead, you can inherit from it, and only  add a few small methods, so you can reuse most of the methods of the original class.

Comment: Inheriting to reuse code is missing both the point of inheritance ("is a" relationship) and a much greater source of code reuse: Polymorphism.

Comment: but in Inheritance you have to rewrite the code also if you want different implementation i.e, overriding. So we can also do it here include header file implement new method and use this library everywhere with customize implementation of method.

Answer (score 0):

It is important here not to confuse language support for OOP and OOP itself. The common practice for re-usable C code is to define data types and functions operating on the data types in an header file, and then implement functions in terms of these data types and functions. When you look at it closely, this is an implementation of OOP, even though without proper language support and thus less stable. But: A C header file that typedefs data structures and functions operating on these data structures is an implementation of OOP.

Therefore, there is no difference in code reusability, it is just a view on two different layers. OOP is about a paradigm, C headers about an implementation in the C context.